# One home Windows 10 machine can see but not access another

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access

### Problem

One Windows 10 home computer cannot remote desktop or access shares on the other.

### Network

[image: Network]

### Symptoms

1. RDP Error on HomeA (this occurs whether I use name or IP number):

   > ```
   > Remote Desktop can’t find the remote computer “HomeB”. 
   > This might mean that “HomeB” does not belong to the specified network.  
   > Verify the computer name and domain that you are trying to connect to.
   > ```
2. Attempting to view a share on HomeB from HomeA results in error:

   > ```
   > You do not have permission to access \\HomeB\temp. 
   > Contact your network administrator to request access.
   > ```
3. Macbook can RDP to both HomeA and HomeB
4. HomeA can RDP to Office
5. From HomeA,

   ```
   Test-NetConnection -ComputerName HomeB -Port 3389
   ```

   results in

   > ```
   > ComputerName     : homeb  
   > RemoteAddress    : 192.168.1.x  
   > RemotePort       : 3389  
   > InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet  
   > SourceAddress    : 192.168.1.y  
   > TcpTestSucceeded : True
   > ```
6. Network Neighborhood shows both HomeA and HomeB (on both)
7. Both machines share c:\temp with all authenticated users
   a. HomeB can see and access share on HomeA
   b. HomeA can see but not access share on HomeB
   c. Using the command, net use \HomeB\temp /user:HomeB\user gives:

   > > ```
   > > Multiple connections to a server or share resource by the same user…
   > > ```
   > >
   > > “net use” shows no connections to HomeB

### Configuration

HomeA and HomeB have the same configurations:

1. OS
   a. Windows 10 Pro 1903
   b. Workgroup: Workgroup
   c. Remote Desktop enabled
   d. SMB 1 disabled
2. Network
   a. IPv6 disabled
   b. IPv4 DHCP, both 192.168.1.x
   c. Netbios disabled
3. Services
   a. fdPHost, Automatic, Running
   b. FDResPub, Automatic, Running
4. Accounts
   a. Both machine have account, user, that is an administrator
   b. Both have the same password
   c. HomeA\user is linked to a Microsoft account; HomeB\user is not
   d. Windows credentials has no stored passwords for the target machine
5. Firewall
   a. Remote Desktop inbound allowed
   b. No outbound rules

It appears to be an authentication issue on HomeB but I can't figure out why.
What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure Network Discovery and File / Print sharing are enabled on both Windows computers. Verify that password protected sharing is enabled. Now restart both computers and on one computer, open cmd.exe and run NET USE Z: \\ipaddressofothercomputer\folder , authenticate and then post what numerical system error you get.

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, I turned password protected sharing off.  After turning it on I can map \\homeb\temp so that is a step forward. RDP still does not work. :-(

Comment: Look through all the advanced settings of RDP: General (Credentials and ensure correct), and Advanced (Connect from Anywhere and ensure correct). RDP should work if NET USE works.

Comment: Change that, it works now. I guess my symptoms make sense now.  If you want to move that from a comment to a response, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Yes, I had copied another RDP connection which had a remote gateway set.  That was my own oversight.  Because I couldn't map the drive, I didn't think to check the RDP settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

Make sure Network Discovery and File / Print sharing are enabled on both Windows computers. Verify that password protected sharing is enabled.

Now restart both computers and on one computer, open cmd.exe and run NET USE Z: \ipaddressofothercomputer\folder , authenticate and then post what numerical system error you get.

Now look at RDP.  Look through all the advanced settings of RDP: General (Credentials and ensure correct), and Advanced (Connect from Anywhere and ensure correct). RDP should work if NET USE works.
That will assist you